# Suppressing conflicts behaviour on load does not affect dependent packages

Tags: r, warnings, package

**TL;DR:** Shouldn't `warn.conflicts = FALSE` suppress warnings for dependent packages as well?

Imagine we have a situation when we attach a package `pkg1` with `library` or `require`, which has conflicts with e.g. `package:base` or `.GlobalEnv`. By default, we will see a warning:

```
library(zoo)
# has a warning about as.Date
```

which can be suppressed:

```
detach("package:zoo", unload = T)
library(zoo, warn.conflicts = F)
# does not have a warning
```

Now, let us have `pkg2`, which depends on `pkg1` and loads it. Assume `pkg2` also has conflicts. It is rather natural to expect that attaching `pkg2` with `warn.conflicts = F` should suppress warnings from both `pkg1` and `pkg2`, however, it is not so:

```
detach("package:zoo", unload = T)
as.xts <- function() {cat("dummy")}
library(xts)
# has warnings about both as.Date and as.xts

detach("package:xts", unload = T)
detach("package:zoo", unload = T)
library(xts, warn.conflicts = F)
# still has a warning about as.Date (?!)
```

The question is, why is the suppressing behaviour not inherited? If there's a solid reason behind that, why it is not stated explicilty in the documentation? If that's unintentional, is it worth proposing to be fixed?

**PS** My use case is the following: I'm capturing an error log from an R script. I'm interested in all warnings and errors, except for conflict warnings, since I'm sure this won't be a problem. I have two solutions for the situation above:

1. Call `library(zoo, warn.conflicts = F)` first, then `library(xts, warn.conflicts = F)`. Not convenient if many dependencies are present.
2. Use `suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(xts, warn.conflicts = F))`. Not sure if I lose some important information I might be interested in, e.g. a message from authors on package update, etc.

Relevant parts from `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

other attached packages:
[1] xts_0.9-7  zoo_1.7-11
```

**PPS** I've checked the source of `library`: `warn.conflicts` is only used once and calls `checkConflicts` if `TRUE`, but I do not see it being passed over to anywhere else.

Comment: Those aren't necessarily warnings.  Many are package startup messages. Did you try `quietly = TRUE`  in `library`?

Comment: @RichardScriven Ah, yes, forgot to mention that. I did, and I actually use it in the script, and it does not affect the behaviour I describe.

Comment: Ok.  Yeah they can be a pain. `plyr` and `dplyr` fill up my whole screen when I load them.

Comment: @RichardScriven Exactly, and while in the interactive session this may be tolerable, with Rscript being called externally I'd like to get rid of it to keep the error log relatively clean.